# How to prevent Firebug cancelling custom key/mouse events

Tags: jquery, events, binding, firebug

Using jQuery I've binded actions to the four cursor key events.

Problem is, if I then run Firebug the cursor key events are lost, which renders the web app I'm coding pretty much useless - the cursor keys move SVG elements around the canvas.

Any ideas y'all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Onclick event override with firebug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783588/onclick-event-override-with-firebug)

Comment: @T Nguyen Thanks for making me smile.

Comment: @JB King It seems that Firebug (and possibly any other plugin than requires cursor control) is overriding the cursor events upon focus of the Firebug window, but when it loses focus it doesn't return my cursor events back to their original state. So far, this only seems to effect cursor key events.

Comment: Firebug shouldn't catch any key or mouse events as long as it isn't focused (with a few exceptions like e.g. the inspect shortcut). If it does, you should ask in the discussion group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebug giving a reproducible test case (http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Creating_a_Test_Case).